# Reading multiple csv files in R while specifying column type

Tags: r, csv, dplyr, reader

I am using this code to read in muptiple csv files in r from a folder.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim)
```

I want to specify the column types while doing this step. How is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Try `myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim, colClasses = a_vector_of_col_classes)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim, colClasses = a_vector_of_col_classes)